# Confusion matrix and precision problem

Tags: machine-learning, python, neural-network, machine-learning-model

I'm trying to calculate the precision of a trained model. I have generated the right values for the true positive rate and the false positive rate. And I know that the formula should be TP/TP + FP.
But I can't seem to generate the right values in python.

My code:

```
true_positives_0 = confusion_matrix_0[0, 0]
false_positives_0 = confusion_matrix_0[0, 1]
precision_sex_0 = true_positives_0 / (true_positives_0 + false_positives_0)

true_positives_1 = confusion_matrix_1[0, 0]
false_positives_1 = confusion_matrix_1[0, 1]
precision_sex_1 = true_positives_1 / (true_positives_1 + false_positives_1)

print("The precision for sex 0 is: {:0.3f}".format(precision_sex_0))
print("The precision for sex 1 is: {:0.3f}".format(precision_sex_1))
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Welcome to DataScienceSE. It depends how your `confusion_matrix_0` and `confusion_matrix_1` have been initialized, this is probably where the problem is. Generally it does not make sense to take the precision of both classes in a binary problem.

Answer (score 6):

I think you retrieved the wrong values for tn, tp, fn, fp.

The [confusion matrix from sklearn is](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.confusion_matrix.html)

The proper way to retrieve these numbers is:

```
tn, fp, fn, tp = confusion_matrix(y_true, y_pred)
```

Hope this helps!